# PHP7 - SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I have the problem to retrieve information from SQL server database. 
But no problem to insert data.

this is the simple code:

```
$serverName = "xx.xx.xx.xx\SQLEXPRESS,1433";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "Test",
    "Uid" => "User",
    "PWD" => "Password"
);

$connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

if (!connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mssql_get_last_message() ); 
} else {
    echo("Connected Successfully </br>" );
}

$sql = " INSERT INTO Imaging (ap) VALUES (1)"; 
$result = sqlsrv_query( $connection, $sql);
```

This code working perfectly.

But if I trying to retrieve data

```
$sql = "select ap from Imaging ";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $connection, $sql);

var_dump($result);
```

I have this result. 
Connected Successfully
resource(2) of type (SQL Server Statement)

What is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: var_dump($result); what does this print?

Comment: Connected Successfully resource(2) of type (SQL Server Statement)

Comment: Thank you WillParkky93.  It's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `$result` is a resource;
From the [man page of sqlsrv_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) your code must be like so:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {    
    echo $row['ap'];    
}
```